# evaluate the value of a expression in java using beanshell by passing variable to Math.pow( )

Tags: java, beanshell

i was trying to evaluate a expression in java directly, though it is a easy expression , it seems difficult to me by using beanshell

anyway , this is my problem:

i can directly evaluate a value of exponential by using in java

```
double c = Math.pow(2,3);
```

or another way

```
int a=2,b=3;
double c = Math.pow(a,b);
```

In Beanshell i am trying to do the same , it works:

```
import bsh.Interpreter;
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
int a1=2, b1=3;
String equation = "Math.pow(2,3)";
Object checkIt = interpreter.eval(equation);
System.out.println(checkIt.toString);
```

but these lines dont work:

```
String equation = "Math.pow(a1,b1)";
Object checkIt = interpreter.eval(equation);
System.out.println(checkIt.toString);
```

**[**this is my progress](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14512932/)****

update : my code shows me the error message
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``Math.pow(finalStr,2);'' : Undefined argument:

Comment: how should bsh know of a1 and b1. you need to inject them in the shell manually, I suppose?

Comment: i think so , but i don't know how to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BeanShell script does not have access to Java local variables. The script can only see values that have been given to the BeanShell [`Interpreter`](http://www.beanshell.org/javadoc/bsh/Interpreter.html) using any of the `set()` methods:

```
import bsh.Interpreter;
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.set("a1", 2);
interpreter.set("b1", 3);
String equation = "Math.pow(a1,b1)";
Object checkIt = interpreter.eval(equation);
System.out.println(checkIt);
```

The [javadoc](http://www.beanshell.org/javadoc/bsh/Interpreter.html) even has examples of this.

Comment: i logged in to vote up your perfect answer. thank you very much!